# Skip empty colum in Python/xlrd

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlrd

> 71456     BUCKET       **8/01/2024**

> 666654    VALVE

> 90000     TYRE

I have the aforementioned content available in a Excel sheet. I would like to store the information in a list, but ONLY when the last column mentions a date.

The script doesn't work properly as unnessary rows without content in the last column are being stored in the list.

I have noticed that the previous value from the last colum was passed to it. Can anyone help me?

Here's my code so far:

```
import xlrd
excel = "stock.xls"
from datetime import datetime, date

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read Excel

content = xlrd.open_workbook(excel)

#get content

sheet_brussels = content.sheet_by_index(0)
tools_brussels = []
startdate = date(2022, 1, 1)

#Brussels
for w in range (sheet_brussels.nrows):
    if ( w >= 1):
        part = sheet_brussels.cell_value(w, 0)
        last_sale_date = sheet_brussels.cell_value(w, 7)
        print(last_sale_date)
        if last_sale_date != "" or last_sale_date != 0:
            try:
                datetime_date = xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(last_sale_date, 0)
                date_object = datetime_date.date()
            except:
                pass
        if part not in tools_brussels and date_object >= startdate:
            tools_brussels.append(part)
print(tools_brussels)
```

I can't figure out how to skip the last colum when this does not mention any date.